# Prove, that generating function for $0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,1,3,1,...$ is $\frac{x^7}{1-x} + \frac{2x^7}{1-x^2}$

Tags: generating-functions

Prove, that generating function for $0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,1,3,1,...$ is $$\frac{x^7}{1-x} + \frac{2x^7}{1-x^2}$$
I have a really problem with understanding generating function, so I don't show my attempt so I am asking for advice.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @bof. These numbers are the coefficients of the expansion built at $x=0$.

Comment: I don't understand your sequence. Is it $$0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,1,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,1,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,1,3,1,0,0,\dots$$ or is it $$0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,1,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,\dots?$$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yes, it is clear what the sequence is, from the given generating function. It just seems to be, as a matter of esthetics perhaps, that in an exercise to prove A = B, each of the terms A and B should have a clear definition independently of the other. And to me it does not seem at all clear what is supposed to come after 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,1,3,1.

Comment: @bof. I totally agree with you (after thinking more, just as I should have done it !). Cheers :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To say that $g(x)$ is the (ordinary) generating function of a sequence $\langle a_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is to say that

$$g(x)=\sum_{n\ge 0}a_nx^n\;.$$

Let’s look at an example using some of the ideas that you need for your problem. Suppose that we want the generating function of the sequence

$$\langle 0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,4,0,0,4,0,0,4,\ldots\rangle\;;\tag{0}$$

this sequence starts with $5$ zeros and then repeats the terms $4,0,0$ forever. Forget that first bit: the basic structure is $\langle 4,0,0,4,0,0,4,0,0,\ldots\rangle$. Any regular cycling like this is easy to generate. The simplest example is

$$\frac1{1-x}=\sum_{n\ge 0}x^n\;,\tag{1}$$

from the formula for the sum of a geometric series; the coefficient of $x^n$ is $1$ for each $n\ge 0$, so $(1)$ is the generating function and power series for the sequence $\langle 1,1,1,1,\ldots\rangle$. I don’t want ones for my non-zero terms, though: I want fours. That’s easily arranged: multiply $(1)$ by $4$ to get

$$\frac4{1-x}=4\sum_{n\ge 0}x^n=\sum_{n\ge 0}4x^n\;,\tag{2}$$

corresponding to the sequence $\langle 4,4,4,4,\ldots\rangle$ of coefficients.

Of course I also want the fours to occur only every third term, not every term. This is almost as easy to arrange, still using the formula for the sum of a geometric series. The trick is to replace the ratio $x$ in the geometric series by $x^3$, so that $(1)$ becomes

$$\frac1{1-x^3}=\sum_{n\ge 0}(x^3)^n=\sum_{n\ge 0}x^{3n}\;,$$

with coefficient sequence $\langle 1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,\ldots\rangle$, and $(2)$ becomes

$$\begin{align*}
\frac4{1-x^3}&=4\sum_{n\ge 0}(x^3)^n=\sum_{n\ge 0}4x^{3n}\\\\
&=4x^0+0x^1+0x^2+4x^3+0x^4+0x^5+4x^6+0x^7+0x^8+\ldots\;,
\end{align*}\tag{3}$$

with coefficient sequence $\langle 4,0,0,4,0,0,4,0,0,\ldots\rangle$.

Now all we need is to push $5$ zeros in front of this sequence of coefficients. In other words, instead of having

$$4x^0+0x^1+0x^2+4x^3+0x^4+0x^5+4x^6+0x^7+0x^8+\ldots\;,$$

we want to start with the five zero terms

$$0x^0+0x^1+0x^2+0x^3+0x^4$$

and *then* have the coefficients cycling $4,0,0,4,0,0,\ldots$:

$$0x^0+0x^1+0x^2+0x^3+0x^4+\color{blue}{4x^5+0x^6+0x^7+4x^8+0x^9+0x^{10}+\ldots}\;.$$

Notice that the cycling part, in blue, is just $x^5$ times the series in $(3)$: multiplying by $x^5$ pushes all of the coefficients $5$ terms to the right, and of course the $5$ new low-order terms are all $0$. Thus, the generating function of the sequence $(0)$ is

$$\frac{4x^5}{1-x^3}\;.$$

Your problem is both easier and harder. It’s easier, because you already have the generating function and merely have to explain why it generates the given sequence of coefficients. It’s a little harder, because you have to see how the two summations combine. If you’re having trouble, I would start by seeing what sequences correspond to the functions

$$\frac1{1-x}\quad\text{and}\quad\frac2{1-x^2}\;:$$

turn those fractions into power series using the ideas above, write out the first several terms of each, and see what pattern of coefficients you get — i.e., what sequences these functions generate. Then add the sequences term by term to see what

$$\frac1{1-x}+\frac2{1-x^2}$$

generates. Finally, see what effect the multiplication by $x^7$ has.

Comment: @user180834: You’re very welcome!

Comment: You are great man!
You explained me really good. :)
Can I with my original proof determine function and show, that they are equal?

Comment: If you don't understand, tell me it. English isn't my native language so I may make a mistake.

Comment: @user180834: I’m glad that it helped. I’m not sure what you’re referring to when you speak of your original proof. It is possible to start with your sequence and actually derive the generating function $\frac{x^7}{1-x}+\frac{2x^7}{1-x^2}$ without knowing ahead of time, using the ideas in my answer, but you don’t have to do quite that much, since you already know what the function is.

Comment: Ok, but I would like:
I assume that I don't know the generating function and I have a sequence: $0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,1,3,1.....$ And now I detemine function generating for it and check that it is equal given. Ok?

Comment: @user180834: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19595/discussion-between-user180834-and-brian-m-scott).

Answer (score 2):

Hint:$$\frac{x^7}{1-x} + \frac{2x^7}{1-x^2}
\\=x^7\left(
\frac1{1-x}+\frac2{1-x^2}\right)
\\=x^7\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k+2\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{2k}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. Try to use that
$$
\frac{1}{1-x^n} = 1 + x^n + x^{2n} + \dots
$$